# Eclipse Integrated development environment

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have an IDE for java (and android), also recently have downloaded the ide for php development.
Is it possible to use both (not at the same time) ide's from the same application?
Now i have eclipse juno for java and eclipse luna for php...

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains is the best IDE on the market.  You can use it for web, Java, and Android development.

Comment: well, perhaps.
But i wanted to know if, somehow, it's possible to use those two ide's under same installation...

Comment: Sounds ridiculous to me.  I'd want to use one IDE that could solve both problems, not switch back and forth.

Comment: Anyhow. Besides the fact that some people might find this ridiculous. Can somebody please answer me the following question:
Is it possible to merge two(or more) different IDE under one eclipse application/executable

Comment: Why there are no replies?
what's wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to download c++ ide into the eclipse version that i used for java.
Basically look for p2 software repository of the IDE of your choice and paste the link into: work with, under install new software, under help.
Now i have 2 different IDE's working under same application (should be possible to have more)

Also a comment to the downvoter: It is not wise to downvote without explaining the reason of your action.... 
Some food for thought...